# Does $\big( \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial x^1 \partial x^3}-\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial x^3 \partial x^1}\big)=0$?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms

I was given this general $2$-form on $\mathbb{R}^3$

$$\omega= A(x^1,x^2,x^3) \ dx^1 \wedge dx^2 +B(x^1,x^2,x^3) \ dx^1 \wedge dx^3+C(x^1,x^2,x^3) \ dx^2 \wedge dx^3$$

and was asked to write down explicit conditions on $A$, $B$, and $C$ which are equivalent to:

i. $d\omega=0$

ii. $\omega = d \alpha$, where $\alpha$ is a $1$-form and $\alpha=F\ dx^1+G\ dx^2+ H\ dx^3$.

iii. Show that the conditions from (ii.) imply those of (i.).

Here is what I got so far:

i. The condition that makes $d\omega=0$ is $\frac{\partial A}{\partial x^3}-\frac{\partial B}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial C}{\partial x^1}=0$.

ii. The conditions that make $\omega=d\alpha$ are

1. $A=\frac{\partial G}{\partial x^1}-\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^2}$
2. $B=\frac{\partial H}{\partial x^1}-\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^3} $
3. $C=\frac{\partial H}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial G}{\partial x^3}$

iii. $\frac{\partial A}{\partial x^3}-\frac{\partial B}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial C}{\partial x^1}=\big( \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial x^1 \partial x^3}-\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial x^3 \partial x^1}\big) +\big( \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^3 \partial x^2}-\frac{\partial^2  F}{\partial x^2 \partial x^3} \big)+\big(\frac{\partial^2 H}{\partial x^2 \partial x^1} -\frac{\partial^2 H}{\partial x^1 \partial x^2}\big)$

The thing I am not sure about is weather this expression in (iii) equals $0$ or not. Does it equal $0$? Thank you!

Comment: In short, yes! In long, [yes!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives)

Comment: What smoothness hypotheses do you have?

Comment: @TedShifrin sorry I am not sure what you’re asking about exactly. My professor didn’t mention anything about the smoothness in this problem.

Comment: So you know nothing about existence/continuity of second-order partial derivatives?

Comment: @TedShifrin oh are you talking about $C^\infty$?

Comment: For example. $C^2$ would be highly relevant to your question.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ok then I know what you meant, I just misunderstood your question, sorry. I think $G, H,$ and $F$ are all smooth ($\in C^\infty)$. They have infinite number of derivatives and they all are continuous.

Comment: Then you should know a theorem that answers your question!

Comment: @TedShifrin It has been a while since I studied calculus. I just felt that it is not necessarily true and tried to find a counter example but couldn’t find any. So I reached out for help to refresh my memory :) I know the theorem now!

Comment: OP: if you have found a solution to your question, I encourage you to post it as an answer to your own post, so that it may help future users, instead of deleting it.